# Wait Inside While Loop to Periodically Check Status

Tags: c#, .net, timer, wait

I have a simple process that sends a request to an API, waits until the API has returned a response, and then continues on with this response. I would like to avoid sleeping the main thread as this will be run as a service and I don't want to block starts/stops.

Is there anyway to achieve this with a Timer?

My code looks something like:

```
string RequestID = api.SendRequest(info);
DateTime fiveMinutesFromNow = GetFiveMinutesFromNow();
ApiResponse response = null;

while (response != null && now < fiveMinutesFromNow)
{
     ApiResponse check = api.GetResponse(RequestID);
     if(check.status == "Complete")
     {
          response = check;
          break;
     }else
     {
          //Wait for 3 seconds
     }
}

if(response.status == "Complete")
{
//Continue on
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's my current revision using an AutoResetEvent.  Thoughts?

```
class MyClass
{
    private Api _api = new Api();
    private ApiResponse _response = new ApiResponse();
    private EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private string _requestID;
    private readonly Object _criticalSection = new Object();

    void DoStuff()
    {
        Info info = GetInfo();
        _requestID = _api.SendRequest(info); 
        Thread pollingThread = new Thread(PollReutersAPI);
        pollingThread.isBackground = true; 
        pollingThread.Start();

        _waitHandle.Reset();
        if (!_waitHandle.WaitOne(300000))
        {
            pollingThread.Abort();
        }     

        if(_response.status == "Complete")
        {
            //Continue on
        }
    }

    void PollApi()
    {
         while(true)
         {
              ApiResult check = _api.GetResponse(_requestID);
              lock(_criticalSection)
              {
                  if(check.status == "Complete")
                  {
                      _response = check; 
                      _waitHandle.Set();
                      return;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Thread.Sleep(3000);
                  }
              }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't do this on start/stop threads? If you're spawning a worker thread on start, it won't matter if it's blocked when the service is stopping.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. Nonetheless, this is still something I'd like to learn. If this were just existing in a console app, how would you go about it?

Comment: Probably create a System.Threading.Timer to wait three seconds.  You just have to make sure the instance of this class is referenced by the application, and that the class holds a reference to the Timer, so the GC doesn't come by and clean it up.  Or I'd be lazy and Wait(Timespan.FromSeconds(3)) on a Mutex, blocking the current thread.

Comment: Read [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) and you will have good understanding how to achieve this task

Comment: bjan gave you a very informative link that should give you all you need

Comment: The link is great. I'm still working through the material. From what I've read, an AutoResetEvent fits well into this issue. I'll post what I've worked out so far. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try spinning up a task to avoid the main thread all together.  Try something like this:

```
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private string RequestID;
    ApiResponse response;

    private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        freeUI();
    }

    private void do_stuff()
    {
        RequestID = api.SendRequest(info);
        DateTime fiveMinutesFromNow = GetFiveMinutesFromNow();
        response = null;

        while (response != null && now < fiveMinutesFromNow)
        {
            ApiResponse check = api.GetResponse(RequestID);
            if (check.status == "Complete")
            {
                response = check;
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                break;  // <-- maybe you could remove this since the task was cancelled?
            }
            else
            {
                //Wait for 3 seconds
            }
        }

        if (response.status == "Complete")
        {
            //Continue on
        }
    }

    private async Task freeUI()
    {
        await start_process();

        // do other things
    }

    private Task start_process()
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = tokenSource.Token;

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            do_stuff();

        }, token);
    }
```

I use this sort of thing for rebinding databound objects or performing large heavy tasks where I want the UI to remain responsive.  Since I don't have your API I can't test this but it should work.